# Remote desktop login time and duration of session

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

We have server where only one worker is connecting using remote desktop.
I want to check how long did each session last.
Found out that in event viewer through ID 4624 I can filter all logins, but cant see logouts. (or time for each session).

Comment: Did you dig a little deeper into the Windows Security logs to see the "logoff" entries? Additionally, did the user log off, or did they simply close their session and re-connect to it later (this isn't a logoff)?

Comment: User simply closes his session (disconects through remote desktop), never "logoff".